# How to get value from global variables in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to get a value from a global variable which is in the response code. I have tried regex and Beanshell code, but still I am getting the values as null. Can someone help me with this?

My beanshell code:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
String path=FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();
String sid= vars.get("whiteboardVars");
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("/Users/diya/testgui/sesid.csv", true); //spec-ify true if you want to overwrite file. Keep blank otherwise.
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
p.println(sid);
f.close();
```

[Debug sampler output- whiteboardVars = 0 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OaqP.png)

[Search of whiteboardVars which exists in the response data of the http request. My main target is to get the sessionId from the whiteboardVars variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZw5c.png)

Comment: Can you share your regular expression?

Comment: Sure @ararar It is, ** Reference Name = wbVars ** , ** Regular Expression = "whiteboardVars":"(.+?)" ** , ** Template = $1$ **

Comment: And which value are you trying to get from the response, is it the full payload for whiteboardVars? or only session id?

Comment: I would like to just get the sessionID from that whiteboardVars global variable @ararar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if your `whiteboardVars` variable really has the value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) combination. If the variable is not defined your attempt to write it into a file will not make sense so double check that it has the value.
2. Be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting. You will be able to shorten your code to this line:

   ```
   new File('/Users/diya/testgui/sesid.csv').newWriter().withWriter { w -> w << vars.get('whiteboardVars') }
   ```

   and it will be way faster.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response @Dmitri T. I verified it with debug sampler and it appears in my search in the response code of the results tree(So I confirm that it is present). I have tried using the code which you mentioned above in the JSR223 Pre-processor and it still it gives value as null in my csv file

Comment: Please update your question with a screenshot of your Test Plan and let me know once done. Try to have log viewer window open as well if there are any errors

Comment: I have updated two images in the question. @Dmitri T Please let me know if you need any other inputs. Also there are no errors, as i said i am receiving the value as null but no error

Comment: Your regular expression extractor doesn't work, you need to amend your regular expression to something like `"sessionId":(\d+),`. If you have problems with creating regular expressions - go for [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter)  which should be easier to use. Make sure to switch the Post Processor scope to **Body**

Comment: It is working now after updating the regular expression to "sesionId":(\d+). Thank you so much @Dmitri T.

Comment: Also, How can I add one more variable value to the csv file with groovy script. Like if I want to add the uname from the result? @Dmitri T